# Audio file upload form not working

Tags: php, forms, post, audio

I've got the following simple form:

```
<form method='POST' action='upload.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="message">
    <button type='submit' value='submit'>Upload Message</button>
</form>
```

I also have some validation, simplified here:

```
if(isset($_FILES['message']) || !empty($_FILES['message']['name']) ){
    //validation here
}else{
    //if no file is set, we repeat the form.
}
```

This code seems to work validating all kinds of files. BUT the problem comes when I try to upload audio files. When I do that, the `if` statement doesn't return true and I end up in the `else` section, seeing my form again as if I've done nothing. How do I make the page recognize that an audio file was uploaded?

So far, I've tried removing the `if/else` statement altogether, but then my validation just spits out an error saying I've got an undefined index `$_FILES['message']`.

I've also made certain to set my php.ini upload_max_filesize and post_max_size, to no avail.

Comment: no, it's not validating files. $_FILES can still contain information even if the upload failed. you need to check the `['error']` parameter in there. that's why it's there: things fail, and you should never be assuming success. Checking `['error']` must be the FIRST thing you do, because anything else is pointless if the upload failed.

Comment: also, your `||` should be an `&&`. You want to require that both of those things are set and not just one or the other.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after editing the php.ini?

Comment: @imtheman Ha. It's always the easiest thing that gets you. Restarting fixed the problem. Oh irony. I'd have solved the problem myself without asking if I'd have just waited to ask until I booted up again. Thank you!